How to change the color of text function in android app? (using android studio)
How does one change the text color, font and other attributes of the Text() function?
or is there some completely different way I should be adding text?
I started from the "empty activity" and am trying to figure out this program.
I am trying to make a simple app in Android studio, but I keep running into extremely not user friendly design choices and confusing way the element attributes are specified. The tutorials available online are all completely different and almost as if everyone is using different programs... even the sample code I get on starting fresh project is different than those guides show. I am definitely NOT fronted person, I have no instincts for it and the Android Studio is NOT helping.
despite trying to set the
<item name= "android:textColor"> 

to just about any possible configuration, the Text() function always prints in black, and trying to add color directly with
Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier,
        color = "0xffffff"
    )

it just breaks the function, I get "none of the following functions can be called with arguments supplied"
what is the correct way to do it?

Compose Text function does not accept Strings as Color that's your problem, it requires Color type, an example function may look like this:
@Composable
fun Example1() {
    Text(
        text = "hello",
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
    )
}

and it references a color from the colors.xml
another way looks like this:
@Composable
fun Example1() {
    Text(
        text = "hello",
        color = Color.Black
    )
}

I highly recommend checking the type of the argument (with either ctrl+P or command+P) before typing it out, just to double check :)
more about styling the Text composable you can find here or here

also, you will not be able to set styles (through XML styles in compose)!
